# Не выдаются привилегии пользователю в Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

У меня есть пакет с процедурами, которые определены.У меня есть c##user. Я хочу выдать пользователю привилегии таким образом: grant execute on shop_reg.registration to c##user, но у меня ошибка: "procedure function package or package body does not exist"

[image: package]

Answer (score 0):

привилегию в Oracle можно выдать только на объект схемы. процедура внутри пакета не является объектом схемы.